# React GUI doesn't update when I sort the Array State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, next.js

In my Next.js application I have a state with an array of objects, and I map this objects returning a Profile.jsx component for each object. The problem is that I have a "Order Combat" button, that sort the array by the "init" property. When I click it, it sorts perfectly, when I console log it, the state shows the order I expect, but in the GUI, it continues showing the previous order before I sorted it

I already saw some Questions similar to mine, but NONE of their answers worked for me... I even tried making the list that contains the elements into a single component

For context, this is the state and the function that sorts it

```
const [ combatList, setCombatList ] = useState<Character[]>([])
function sortCombatList() {
    const sortedList = [...combatList]
    sortedList.sort((c1, c2) => c2.init - c1.init)
    setCombatList(sortedList)
}
```

The **Character** type have the properties the objects should have, just in case this could help someone, this is the type itself:

```
export type Character = {
    id: number,
    playerId?: string,
    name: string,
    init: number,
    type?: string,
    attacks?: Attack[]
    life: number,
    actualLife: number,
    mentalEnergy: number,
    actualMentalEnergy: number,
    da: number,
}
```

Continuing, this is the map function and the Profile component
**Map Function**

```
{Children.toArray(combatList.map?.(
    combatent => <Profile
        removeFromCombatList={removeFromCombatList}
        updateProfileInCombatList={updateProfileInCombatList}
        obj={combatent}
    />
))}
```

**Profile Component**

```
export default function Profile ({
    removeFromCombatList,
    updateProfileInCombatList,
    obj
}: ProfileProps) {
    const [ profileState, setProfileState ] = useState<Character>(obj)

    function changeActualLife(value: number) {
        setProfileState({
            ...profileState,
            actualLife: value
        })
    }
    function changeActualMentalEnergy(obj: { value?: number, amount?: number }) {
        setProfileState({
            ...profileState,
            actualMentalEnergy: obj.value?obj.value:
                obj.amount?profileState.actualMentalEnergy+obj.amount:profileState.actualMentalEnergy
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updateProfileInCombatList(profileState.id, profileState)
    }, [ profileState ])

    return <div>
        <BsFillTrashFill onClick={() => removeFromCombatList(obj.id)} />
        <h3>{profileState.name}</h3>
        <p>
            <label htmlFor={`${profileState.id}-init`}>Iniciativa: </label>
            <input
                type="number"
                min={0}
                id={`${obj.id}-init`}
                defaultValue={`${profileState.init}`}
                onChange={e => setProfileState({
                    ...profileState,
                    init: Number(e.target.value)
                })}
            /></p>
        <p>Tipo: {profileState.type || "Player"}</p>
        <Life
            state={profileState}
            changeState={changeActualLife}
        />
        {profileState.mentalEnergy && <MentalEnergy
            state={profileState}
            changeState={changeActualMentalEnergy}
        />}
        <ul>
            { Children.toArray(profileState.attacks?.map((attack: Attack) => {
                console.log(profileState)
                return <AttackField charId={profileState.id} sumMentalEnergy={changeActualMentalEnergy} obj={attack}/>
            }
            )) }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Just giving an example, if I have 3 characters in list: **Clara, Jack and Suzie**, and they have init **9, 20 and 13** simutaniously, when I click to sort it, and console log the state, it appears **Jack, Suzie and Clara**, like it is supposed to be, but when I go see in the application again, it continues **Clara, Jack and Suzie**, it doesn't change.

If you guys need any more information I can give it

Comment: It seems like you didn’t add the key property when iterating over the combatList array. You must add a key property with a unique value for each item when iterating over an array in React. See if that fixes the issue

Comment: Man you really helped, I thought it woundn't be necessary because of the Children.toArray